# GitHub desktop on mac El-Capitan

Tags: github, osx-elcapitan

I have installed on my mac GitHub about 6 months ago and it worked very well. After I have not used it for a small period and I have done all the upgrade (mac, GhitHub and so on). Today I have used again GitHub but It doesn't wish to modify the files when I use the time-line. For instance:
I have create a file X and after when I go back with time-line of GitHub this file remains on my finder. In the past this file is removed by GitHub.

I have tried to do some things like for example to re-install it or to give more permission `(chmod -R ./repository 777)` or to download again the repository but the problem has not disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to *OSX El Capitan*, I needed to turn off System Integrity Protection for directory modification commands to run properly.

To turn off System Integrity Protection, follow below instructions

> 1) Reboot your mac and press “cmd+r” when booting up. This will cause
>   your mac to start in recovery mode.
>
> 2) Then go into utilities > terminal.
>
> 3) Execute the command below:- csrutil disable
>
> 4) Execute the command below:- reboot